# Common class for WPF Containers (Canvas, Grid, etc)

Tags: c#, wpf, containers

I am creating a method that is invoked by a button. The method then adds a canvas to the button's parent container control. So, e.g., the button is on a grid. Then the method creates a canvas that is shown just below the button. But I have 2 issues:

- How can I get a reference to the button's parent container?
- Is there a class for container controls? I don't care if the button is in a grid, a canvas, a Stackpanel, etc. So I am looking for an interface that all types of contianers implement or a class that they inherit.

The second aspect is more important as I could pass a reference to the container manually.

EDIT:

It should look like this (minus the colors, those are only to show the different elements.

[image]

The red canvas is supposed to pop up to handle a confirmation. Maybe even with a nice animation. My idea was to create a class that can be invoked similar to this:

```
MyPopup popup = new MyPopup("Are you sure?", "Yes", "No", delegateFirstButton, delegateSecondButton);
popup.Show();
```

My code so far is not yet a class but only a method. The text parts are hard coded for the moment. The marked line needs to be more flexible and is the reason for my question.

```
public void ShowPopup(Control senderControl)
{
    //I need to have a parameter that accepts all containers instead of this line:
    this.myGrid.Children.Add(popup);

    Border border = new Border();
    popup.Children.Add(border);
    border.Margin = new Thickness() { Top = 10 };
    border.Child= text;
    text.Text = "Are you sure?";
    text.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    popup.SizeChanged += delegate { border.Width = popup.ActualWidth; };

    popup.Children.Add(btn1);
    btn1.Content = "Yes";
    btn1.Height = 22;
    btn1.Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0);
    btn1.Margin = new Thickness() { Left = 15, Top = 35 };

    popup.Children.Add(btn2);
    btn2.Content = "No";
    btn2.Height = 22;
    btn2.Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0);
    btn1.SizeChanged += delegate { btn2.Margin = new Thickness() { Left = 30 + btn1.ActualWidth, Top = 35 }; };

    popup.Height = 70;
    btn2.SizeChanged += delegate
    {
        popup.Width = 45 + btn1.ActualWidth + btn2.ActualWidth;
        updatePositions(senderControl);
    };

    popup.Background = Brushes.Red;

    popup.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    popup.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
}

public void updatePositions(Control senderControl)
{
    Point location = senderControl.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), this.myGrid);

    popup.Margin = new Thickness()
    {
        Left = location.X + (senderControl.ActualWidth / 2) - (popup.Width / 2),
        Top = location.Y + senderControl.ActualHeight + 15
    };
}
```

Comment: what?? do not manipulate UI elements in code in WPF. What do you want that for?? I don't see the reason for `adds a canvas to the button's parent container control.`... Please explain what you need and we can give you a proper way to do it.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. I create a few elements on a canvas in code and need to attach them to an existing container. I have to show this canvas multiple times and to invoke it with a single line of code. Hence I want to encapsualte that in its own method or class.

Comment: `I have to show this canvas multiple times`... That's probably either `DataTemplate` or a `ControlTemplate`... don't manipulate UI elements in code. WPF is not winforms.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But that doesn't really help me...

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you need to do and I can tell you the proper WPF way to do it.

Comment: Why don't you use the `Popup` class for that? instead of trying to roll out your own

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're choosing the hard way to do that.

If you need a popup, then use a [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx).

Otherwise, if for whatever reasons you don't want to use that, You'd better place a grid somewhere near the root of your XAML, and ALWAYS use that as a container:

```
<Window>
   <Grid x:Name="MainUI"/>
   <Grid x:Name="PopupContainer"/>
</Window>
```

Otherwise, you'll almost invariably encounter `Z-Index` problems (if you follow your current approach).

Also, it's a really bad idea to create all that UI stuff in code. Either encapsulate your Yes/No dialog in a `UserControl` or create a proper `Template` for that.

As I said before, avoid at all costs creating/manipulating UI elements in code, as it creates a lot of maintainability issues.